# Microsoft Bot Framework Composer - Not able to Trigger Intent from Buttons

Tags: botframework, chatbot, bot-framework-composer

I am new to MS Botframework Composer and was working on one of my initial chatbots when I noticed that am not able to Trigger Intents from buttons. Although, the same features were working in the tutorials from MS.
Created a simple prompt with two buttons: Help and Cancel. I want that Help and Cancel Intents (Triggers which I have created within the same Dialog) should be triggered whenever a user clicks on the button. Currently, this is not happening for me and need your help to resolve it? Please refer the images to refer the dialog flow and intents.
[HELP and CANCEL Buttons in flow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RjDmo.jpg)

```
`   [Activity
    Text = Select Options?
    SuggestedActions = Help | Cancel 
    ]`
```

[CANCEL Trigger](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nHWxi.jpg)
[Emulator Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DWexw.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with that exact approach (would you mind linking to the portion of the tutorial?), but you can create a Choice Prompt action (Choice Input action from the AskingQuestionsSample is pretty good example). I set mine to be of style `suggestedaction`, then I also set my `allowInterruptions` to true (my cancel and help intents/dialogs are in my main dialog).

```
"actions": [
  {
    "$kind": "Microsoft.ChoiceInput",
    "$designer": {
      "id": "673028",
      "name": "Prompt with multi-choice"
    },
    "property": "user.style",
    "prompt": "Please select a value from below:",
    "maxTurnCount": 3,
    "alwaysPrompt": true,
    "allowInterruptions": "true",
    "outputFormat": "value",
    "choices": [
      {
        "value": "Cancel"
      },
      {
        "value": "Help"
      }
    ],
    "defaultLocale": "en-us",
    "style": "suggestedAction",
    "choiceOptions": {
      "inlineSeparator": ", ",
      "inlineOr": " or ",
      "inlineOrMore": ", or ",
      "includeNumbers": true
    },
    "recognizerOptions": {
      "noValue": false,
      "noAction": false,
      "recognizeOrdinals": true
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve this by defining the intent in main dialog and setting up the action in a new dialog. So, whenever LUIS identified an intent, it will action the new dialog.